# Asp.net Control Inherits Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance, panel

I have created a new class that inherits from System.Web.UI.Webcontrols.Panel.

I am overriding the new classes RenderBeginTag(HTMLTextWriter Writer) method.

Inside this method, how do I determine the width of the panel if it is being set by the CSSClass attribute?

Comment: Do you want to set the panel width at ServerSide OR want to know the width of the panel (set by CSS) at SeverSide?

Answer (score 0):

As the method `RenderBeginTag` is executed on the server and the CSS class runs on the client, I don't think it is not possible to detect the width, unless you parse the CSS file on the server.

But why do you want to know this at all? Could you not just set the class attribute in the rendered HTML output?